# Unable to load `/temp/manifests.js` on https

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, spfx, spfx-webparts

On my SharePoint 2016 on-premise development site workbench, to load my SPFx webpart in the `config\server.json` I have set the `"https": false`. My development site loads on `http` and in my browser console I can see request is sent to `http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js`, it successfully resolved and I can add my webpart to the page to test it.

If I set `"https": true` in `config\server.json` request is made to `https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js` (notice http**s**). But the request returns error as

```
GET https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
Failed to load debug manifests: Error: Error loading https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
    XHR error loading https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
GET http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error loading http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
    XHR error loading http://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js
    at XMLHttpRequest.o (eval at <anonymous> (sp-webpart-workbench-assembly_en-us_1c43756ae201421249073388e4dea068.js:1171), <anonymous>:4:14084)
```

and the page shows:

> Your web part will not appear in the toolbox. Please make sure "gulp
>   serve" is running in a web part project. Please refresh the page once
>   "gulp serve" is running.

When I try to run the webpart on my SharePoint Online workbench with either `"https": true` OR `"https": false` set in `config\server.json`, I am unable to load the webpart with same error as above.

I have deleted the `<homedir>/.gcb-serve-data` directory and run the `gulp trust-dev-cert` again, but it has't worked.

How can I load `/temp/manifests.js` on `https`?

Comment: Gulp trust-dev-cert worked for me on Chrome. Not tested in other browsers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally figured out what was the problem.

1. Before doing `gulp serve` run the command `set NODE_NO_HTTP2=1`. This will allow the `manifestes.js` file to be served over https.
2. Before opening the SharePoint Online workbench, access the URL `https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js` from your browser. It may give you warning that it is not really secure, continue anyway. Now open the SharePoint Online workbench.